# Difference in event model between svg and html

Tags: javascript, svg

Found out that on this example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/169269/group_drag.svg
If I try to use the same code in html, it doesn't work at all:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: evt is not defined`

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question, and list the browsers (including version number) that show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it to work by doing following three things.

1.Change the html code (as shown below)to move the library loading after svg tags have loaded; and also add an id to the svg element:

```
<html>
<div>
<svg>  
<svg id='svgCanvas'> ... <svg> 
<script xlink:href="SVGPan.js"/> 
</html>
```

2.Change the library code to set correct value for root variable:

```
// var root = document.documentElement;
var root = document.getElementById('svgCanvas');
```

3.Change the library code function setupHandlers as follows (mousewheel event now bound to root instead of document):

```
function setupHandlers(root){
//  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') >= 0)
//      document.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleMouseWheel, false); // Chrome/Safari
//  else
//      document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handleMouseWheel, false); // Others

    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') >= 0)
        root.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleMouseWheel, false); // Chrome/Safari
    else
        root.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', handleMouseWheel, false); // Others
}
```

Also see this [related question](https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/issues/detail?id=12).

Answer (score 0):

Embed your svg into a html file.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- solution 1 -->
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="group_drag.svg"></object>
<!-- solution 2 -->
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="group_drag.svg" />
<!-- solution 3 -->
<iframe src="group_drag.svg"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```